# How to resolve range Issue in node_module/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js/131

Tags: angular9

I have a build issue while running a unit test case in angular 9.
environment
Angular CLI: 9.1.12
Node: 15.1.0
OS: win32 x64
error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Same error was coming for me too. I commented the if else block in nodemoodules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js 130. It is because it has undefined value. Now it is working fine. I am beginner, I don't know about the impact else where.

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with karma on node v15, you'll have to downgrade to 14.

Issue at Karma: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3571

See also: [[karma-server]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined - Angular Unit Testing in CI environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64752689/karma-server-typeerror-cannot-read-property-range-of-undefined-angular-u)